# why can not I observe the state property in View

Tags: view, ember.js, state, observers

Why can't I do this:

```
App.FullsizeView = Ember.View.extend({
  stateChange: function () {
    console.log(this.state)
  }.observes('state')
});
```

Error:
Assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of )

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure this error is throwed in that code? I simulated this and nothing happens...

Answer (score 2):

State variable conflicts with Ember (checked on 1.2 and 1.3.0-beta.4 versions). Try to rename both state and stateChange in your code.

The same problem happened to my view -

```
App.ActionBarView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "action-bar",
    stateBinding: "App.accessBarModel"
});
```

replacing stateBinding to "barStateBinding" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `state` property is reserved by Ember to track the internal state of the view (`preRender`, `inBuffer`, `hasElement`, `inDOM`, `destroying`). It is not observable.

Use a different property name if you want to track a different concept of `state`. If you have a use case where you want to observe Ember's `state` property of a view, I would be interested in hearing it.